# How can i send an email in Laravel with a variable name attachment?

Tags: email, email-attachments, laravel-9

I am trying to send an email with an attachment. The attachment filename can vary based on what the user selects. How can I pass the variable to the Attachment method in laravel? When I use the below, I get an error "meta not defined." however, `$meta['title']` is defined. Where $meta['fileName'] is the path to the file in my directory.  If I hardcode the path, it works fine.

**Mail call**

```
$meta['title'] = "Email Title";
$meta['body'] = "Body of email";
$meta['fileName'] = "SomeAttachment.xlsx";

Mail::to($toEmail)->send(new \App\Mail\SendMail($meta));
```

**Sendmail class**

```
class SendMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $meta;

    public function __construct($meta)
    {
        $this->meta = $meta;
    }
    
    public function envelope()
    {
        return new Envelope(
            from: new Address('from@from.com', 'From From'),
            subject: $this->meta['title'],
        );
    }
    
    public function content()
    {
        return new Content(
            view: 'email',
        );
    }
    
    public function attachments()
    {
        return [
            Attachment::fromPath($meta['fileName']),
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Controller:

```
use Illuminate\Mail\Attachment;
use App\Mail\Resend;

$attach = [];
foreach ($aAttachment as $att) {
    $attachment = $att->getContent();

    $attach[] = Attachment::fromData(fn () => $attachment, $att->getName())
                ->withMime($att->getMimeType());
}

Mail::to($to)->send(new Resend($body, $subject, $attach));
```

In (Mailable) app/Mail/Resend.php:

```
class Resend extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $body;
    public $subject;
    public $attach;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($body, $subject, $attach)
    {
        $this->body = $body;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->attach = $attach;
    }

    /**
     * Get the message envelope.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope
     */
    public function envelope()
    {
        return new Envelope(
            subject: 'Fwd: ' . $this->subject,
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the message content definition.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content
     */
    public function content()
    {
        return new Content(
            view: 'emails.Resend',
            with: [
                'body' => $this->body,
            ],
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the attachments for the message.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function attachments()
    {
        return $this->attach;
    }
```

In views/emails/Resend.blade.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>From sabesa.es</title>
</head>
<body>
{!! $body !!}
</body>
</html>
```